# How to use a NSMutableArray as a local cache

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UtilityApp and UITableViewController pushed from the FlipsideViewController. I have modified few cells in the UITableView to embed UITextField and UIButton(save button). The other table view cells would behave normally. On click of a normal UITableViewCell, i would again push the same UITableViewController which has the another set of UITableViewCells. Now my problem is, when i click on the save button i want to add a NSObject onto a NSMUtableArray.
And when i go to the next controller(ie., the same UITableViewController) and click on the save button, again i want to add a NSObject to NSMutableArray. Thus the NSMutableArray behaves as a local cache for me. Hows it possible? Basically i want to declare the NSMutableArray somewhere outside the UITableViewController and keep adding NSObject instances to it. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a singleton class to use as a cache. For example, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like):

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject
{
}

+ (MySingleton *)sharedSingleton;
@end

@implementation MySingleton

+ (MySingleton *)sharedSingleton
{
  static MySingleton *sharedSingleton;

  @synchronized(self)
  {
    if (!sharedSingleton)
      sharedSingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];

    return sharedSingleton;
  }
}

@end
```

Now just use `[MySingleton sharedSingleton]` to get a shared reference to this object. Add methods to add objects to your `NSMutableArray`.